# Transformations at API Management Tool

Tags: api, integration, esb, apigee, apim

This could be typical situation in terms of the integrating/exposing an API.

We are developing an API for internal use and is to be published on the internal hosted APIM platform(APIgee), there were bunch of internal consumers interested in using it but asked for specific response/format etc .

This is where we turned to the APIM team checking the possibilities of transformations so that each consumer can use it in a way that it suits to them.
Interesting point raised by the APIM team was that they dont want to create another middleware .
Now this raises few questions.

What could be better way in these situation where a generic APIs needs some sort of transformation before it can be consumed

- Should APIM (Apigee Edge) handle the transformations ?
- should add another middleware layer to do these transformations ? Like ESB
- Should consumer handle it on its own ?

Generic question could , where these transformations should reside ?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the decision is yours, but Apigee is more than capable of handling average data transformations.
You have multiple options here, personally I recommend using a [javascript policy](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/policies/javascript-policy), because it's easy to implement. Mind you, Apigee uses RhinoJS under the hood.